# Issue with extending a list with another list

Tags: python

**Problem Definition**

Separate each line into sentences. Assume that the following characters delimit sentences: periods ('.'), question marks ('?'), and exclamation points ('!'). These delimiters should be omitted from the returned sentences, too. Remove any leading or trailing spaces in each sentence. If, after the above, a sentence is blank (the empty string, ''), that sentence should be omitted. Return the list of sentences. The sentences must be in the same order that they appear in the file.

**Here is my current code**

```
import re

def get_sentences(doc):
    assert isinstance(doc, list)
    result = []
    for line in doc:
        result.extend(
            [sentence.strip() for sentence in re.split(r'\.|\?|\!', line) if sentence]
        )
    return result

# Demo:
get_sentences(demo_input)
```

**Input**

```
demo_input = ["  This is a phrase; this, too, is a phrase. But this is another sentence.",
                  "Hark!",
                  "    ",
                  "Come what may    <-- save those spaces, but not these -->    ",
                  "What did you say?Split into 3 (even without a space)? Okie dokie."]
```

**Desired Output**

```
["This is a phrase; this, too, is a phrase",
 "But this is another sentence",
 "Hark",
 "Come what may    <-- save those spaces, but not these -->",
 "What did you say",
 "Split into 3 (even without a space)",
 "Okie dokie"]
```

**However, my code produces this:**

```
['This is a phrase; this, too, is a phrase',
 'But this is another sentence',
 'Hark',
 '',
 'Come what may    <-- save those spaces, but not these -->',
 'What did you say',
 'Split into 3 (even without a space)',
 'Okie dokie']
```

**Question: Why am I getting that `''` empty sentence in there even though my code is leaving it out?**

I can solve the problem with the following code but I will have to go through the list again and I don't want to do that. I want to do it in the same pass.

```
import re

def get_sentences(doc):
    assert isinstance(doc, list)
    result = []
    for line in doc:
        result.extend([sentence.strip() for sentence in re.split(r'\.|\?|\!', line)])
        result = [s for s in result if s]
    return result

# Demo:
get_sentences(demo_input)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using `if sentence.strip()`, i.e.:

```
for line in doc:
    result.extend([sentence.strip() for sentence in re.split(r'\.|\?|\!', line) if sentence.strip()])
```